# How can we append new value to a text field without over-writing the existing value

Tags: opportunity

I'm try to build a formula using the Formula Builder to capture the Product Family Name of every Opportunity Product and populate that in a custom text field at the Opportunity level.

For example, if there are three Opportunity Products (having Product Family Names as P1, P2 and P3) for an Opportunity, then I would like to add these names as "P1, P2, P3" in the custom text field of Opportunity. But when I'm trying to do this, it is replacing the existing value with new value (if P1 is stored in that text field and I'm adding a new product, then it is replacing P1 with P2)

Could anyone please help me out with this? I would really appreciate it!

Comment: This would be a great use case for Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries in Concatenate mode.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, I tried building that using the formula builder and I could refer the Custom Text field to have the Product Family Name of Product 1 but when I add the second product, it is replacing the existing value with a new one. Opportunity.Custom_Text_field ==OpportunityLineItem.Product_Family_Name this is the formula I'm using currently.

Comment: If these names will never ever ever change you could Append by concatenating using an IF ( AND( NOT(ISBLANK(...)), INCLUDES(.....))... formula and conditionally append the specific values that you want.

Comment: DLRS is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

The best approach here is to write a Trigger. Or use Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries to do this task for you.